# What specifically prevents the geodesics in Kerr BH from continuing beyond the second world line located inside the inner event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality, kerr-metric

In a Kerr black hole, the inner event horizon is also called the Cauchy horizon.  According to the answer to the question linked here, [why are inner horizons Cauchy horizons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/728172/why-are-inner-horizons-cauchy-horizons), the Cauchy horizon only extends to include the regions of the singularity and the space of the inner event horizon and inner ergosphere.  However, it does not include the region of the next world line located in the area that is enclosed by the ring, and the area on the sides but not on the ring of the singularity.  Basically, the areas further down the multiverse Pennrose Diagram.

My question is why geodesics can't continue in the areas that are not part of the Cauchy horizon in the Kerr black hole.  Furthermore, what do people mean when they say that the ability to get to the region enclosed at the center of the ring singularity is unrealistic and only possible in the ideal and not the real case?

Edit:
I think I did not correctly state the question.  What I meant to ask is, why do we usually refer to the region of the center of the ring singularity, were passing thru leads to another world, as inaccessible in real black holes?

Comment: The way you formulated your problem seems to me very confusing and unclear to a point that I am not sure that I managed to understand what you said. Few things though - 1.) Cauchy horizon is boundary, but you seem to treat it like 4D region of spacetime. 2.) I do not see how did you arrive at the idea that geodesics can't continue beyond Cauchy horizon. Its usually explained, that every timelike curve (i.e. even geodesics) that gets under outer horizon must go beyond inner horizon which, as you said, is Cauchy horizon.

Comment: 3.) in the answer you linked is said that (in RN black hole) region of singularity is not included. In fact, I do not see how that answer suggests anything from what you wrote. Did you linked to the correct page?

Comment: @Umaxo I have added an edit portion to make my question more concise.  In short, why do we usually refer to the region of the center of the ring singularity, where passing thru leads to another world, as inaccessible in real blackholes?